# /etc/initramfs-tools/modules file scssi support

Tags: boot, drivers, kernel

I've recompile the kernel,
and find out it's not booting into second stage because it does not have scsi drivers inside initramfs.

I found out that I need to add entry to /etc/initramfs-tools/modules file, but what to add ? what are the supported module names? I've tried many things but not success.

Any idea?

```
root@nature-Inspiron-3558:/home/nature# for i in $(lspci | grep SATA | sed -e 's/\ .*$//g'); do lspci -v -s $i; done
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 06b0
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 60
    I/O ports at 40b0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 40a0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 4090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 4080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 4060 [size=32]
    Memory at a9219000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
```

Comment: Maybe you have missed the module in the kernel configuration. There are different modules for the various amount of SCSI controllers. You can find out which driver is used for your SCSI controller with `for i in $(lspci | grep SCSI | sed -e 's/\ .*$//g'); do lspci -v -s $i; done`. Then check your kernel configuration.

Comment: The kernel driver in use is ahci ,and I know it and it's dependencies should be included in the initramfs. But the thing is I know how to modify that /etc/initramfs-tools/modules file there.

Comment: and 'lspci | grep SCSI' returns nothing but lspci | grep sata does.

Comment: You can use `lsinitramfs` to verify that the driver is included in the ramdisk. Normally such a standard driver should be included automatically.

Comment: I've verified using the -v option. And there is a way to extract the image and verify, that driver does not exist there. :(